# How to include image path as a source URL in Postman request

Tags: json, postman

I need to include the image file path in the postman request so I don't have to pass the download the image each time and pass it as a file in the 'form-data. I added below request but it throws an error "No file was submitted"

```
"mode": "formdata",
                "formdata": [
                    {
                        "key": "img",
                        "type": "file",
                        "src": "http://<IP>/testdata/8265.jpg"
                    }
```

I tried using escape character ("src": "http:///testdata/8265.jpg") but that did not work either.

Comment: What's the value of `<IP>`? You need to replace it by the actual IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You can set variable for `src` value, I've just tested with file in local machine, not from URL.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Adding a file from the local machine works but I'm trying to figure out how to pass the image URL to the source so I don't have to download the file to my machine each time.

Comment: I don't think postman support this feature.